# How to batch select files that don't respect a pattern

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch

I'm a new user of powershell and cmd and I need to select thousands of files that don't respect a certain pattern. The pattern is as follows : 7num_5num_2num

And I was looking for a way to select these files and so far I have found a command that looks like this :

```
>> find /home/example -iname "*.txt" -exec grep -Li "mystring" {} \+
```

This command finds all the files that include mystring in their names. But from here I don't exactly know how to implement index numbers and I'm  in need of guidance .

Comment: Duplicate of  [I want to batch select multiple files that do not respect a certain rule](https://superuser.com/questions/1730660/i-want-to-batch-select-multiple-files-that-do-not-respect-a-certain-rule) which already has an edit to push to review.

Comment: Edit your other question, rather than making a new one.

Comment: Do the files have an extension(s)???

Comment: they do they are .JPG files @KeithMiller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PowerShell**:

Assumptions:

- Single top-level folder (can be modified to search multiple paths)
- Top-level folder has sub-folders (hence the `-Recurse` parameter)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter '*.jpg' -File -Recurse |
  Where-Object BaseName -notMatch '\d{7}_\d{5}_\d{2}' |
Select-Object Name, FullName
```

Shortened with aliases:

```
gci 'C:\Path\to\Folder' '*.jpg' -af -s | ? BaseName -notMatch '\d{7}_\d{5}_\d{2}' | Select Name, FullName
```

---

### Edit --- *Modifying the match criteria*:

File type selection is limited by the `-Filter` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`. The `-Path` and `-Filter` parameters are processed by the file system provider before the files are returned to **PowerShell**, and thus tend to be faster than subsequent filtering (`-Include`/`-Exclude`).

The `-match` and `-notMatch` operators take [regular expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2), which provide much more precise matching than expressions limited to literals and [wildcards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.2). There's a handy [cheat sheet here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html).

The above returns *all* files that *don't* match the specifed pathern, even those no where close.

To find file names that have less than the desired number of digits, switch to the `-match` operator and use the `{min,max}` quantifier notation, i.e. to match "less than 7 digits", use `\d{0,6}`. If only one section of the file name is likely to be too short, the expression would be very close to the original:

- `Where BaseNaem -match '\d{0,6}_\d{5}_\d{2}'`

If you want to fild files  *close* to the desired pattern, but with fewer than the desired numer of digits in *any* section, specify a count range for each section and also check the overall length:

- `Where { (($_.BaseName.Length -lt 16) -and $_.BaseName -match '\d{1,7}_\d{1,5}_{1,2}') }`

If you want to test the numveric value of any of the sections, test the match first, adding parentheses to save the digits into capture groups, and then use the [`$Matches`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#matches) automatic variable to reference those groups:

- `Where { ($_.BaseName -match '(\d{7})_(\d{5})_(\d{2})') -and ($Matches[2] -gt 10000)  }`

---

References:

- [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1)
- [Where-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)
- [-motMatch operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1#-match-and--notmatch)
- [Select-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)

Comment: Is there a way to specify that the command selects anything inferior to a certain number of indexes ?

Comment: Yes. Do you mean `<fewer than 7>_<fewer than 5>_<fewer than 2>` or something else???

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking for also as for the filtering to only work with the files that have numbers in their names, does this work ? `Get-childitem *.JPG -filter | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '^[0-9_]+$'}`

Comment: The `-filter` without a subsequent string value will throw an error. If you're  in the source directory, you just need `Get-ChildItem *.jpg` to select `.jpg` files. Your regex will limit results to filenames that consist solely of digits and underscores, with no regard to character position or count.

Comment: One more question I have couple of files that are duplicates that either contain BW or Z or copy in their names , can I add them like this ? `gci *.JPG | where-object {$_.Basename -Match '^[0-9_ BWZ copy] +$'}`

Comment: Also I'm not getting any output for some reason

Comment: Comments are lousy for code. Edit your question with screen captures. To troubleshoot, break it down at each stage of the pipeline. Does `gci *.jpg` return files?

Comment: Did you look at the edit I made to my answer?